# Framework 7 how to user vertical dialog button and assign id and class to the button

Tags: javascript, android, html, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

```
$$('.open-vertical').on('click', function () {  app.dialog.create({
title: 'Vertical Buttons',
text: 'Dialog with vertical buttons',
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Button 1',
  },
  {
    text: 'Button 2',
  },
  {
    text: 'Button 3',
  },
],
verticalButtons: true,  }).open();});
```

it shows button but i am unable to use those button.
How to add id and class in this buttons

Answer (score 1):

According to [dialog docs](http://framework7.io/docs/dialog.html#dialog-parameters) there is a function parameter called `onClick` to do something after click on button !

And you can add different behaviour to each button with `index` function parameter

Comment: how can i identify button1,Button 2,or Button 3 is clicked.

Comment: onClick is a function that take 2 params (`function(dialog, index)`) => index correspond will have 3 values for yours 3 buttons.

Comment: Simply add the function to your code, log and test it

Answer (score 1):

```
$$('.open-vertical').on('click', function () {  app.dialog.create({
        title: 'Vertical Buttons',
        text: 'Dialog with vertical buttons',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Button 1',
            },
            {
                text: 'Button 2',
            },
            {
                text: 'Button 3',
            },
        ],
        onClick: function (dialog, index) {
            if(index === 0){
                //Button 1 clicked
                console.log('1');
            }
            else if(index === 1){
                //Button 2 clicked
                console.log('2');
            }
            else if(index === 2){
                //Button 3 clicked
                console.log('3');
            }
        },
        verticalButtons: true,  }).open();});
```

This is basically how to use `onClick` parameter in [framework7 dialog](http://framework7.io/docs/dialog.html#dialog-parameters). With index number you can find out which button is clicked.